# use cx_Freeze let Py33 to exe on windows7 but screen flash and gone

Tags: exe, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I've try everything I can do but still can't see my result on windows screen and stay.
I don't want to use GUI and command prompt. here is my code.

only print('hello, world!') in hello.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name = "hello",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "the typical 'Hello, world!' script",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable("hello.py")]          
      )

input('Press ENTER to continue')
```

Comment: If you double click, Windows will close the console as soon as your program finishes. Put an `input("Press enter to close")` at the end of `hello.py` to make it stick around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is compiling just fine. Your problem is the fact that the program runs too fast to see. It is displaying `'hello world'`, but because there is nothing to keep the program running the program exits and the window closes immediately after it begins. As Thomas K pointed out a simple solution is to add `input()` to the end of your `hello.py` script, in order to keep the program running until the user hits enter. Another option is to create a loop or something along those lines, but `input()` works just fine for keeping text displayed.

Hope this helped.